# RavenDB PeriodicBackup-Temp Files

Tags: ravendb

My RavenDB is running out of space on the SDD and I noticed a large portion of the disk space is being used up by `.ravendb-incremental-dump` files in the `PeriodicBackup-Temp` folder of the database.

Are these files only meant as temporary files as the folder name suggests or are they important?